# Django: django-allauth causes 'Application labels aren't unique'

Tags: python, django

After trying to install django-allauth I run into the following exception:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account`

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'sass_processor',
    'compressor',
    'apps.main',
    'apps.account',
]
```

I figured that it had to do something with my app *account* and I read that after Django 1.7 every app needs a unique label. So I tried setting a label in *apps.py*, but I still get the same exception.

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'account'
    label = 'my_accounts'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have an app called account under apps.account

Comment: in urls.py of apps.account change the name of app.

Comment: add app_name="somename" in urls.py of apps.account

Comment: well of course i noticed i have an app 'accounts' as well, but according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor 'Applications can be relabeled with the label attribute of application configurations, to work around label conflicts.'
So i should be able to just set a different label without renaming the app right?

Comment: yes,you just need to set a different label